# Deleting records using DeleteAllOnSubmit not working with FK contstraints

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, linqpad

Im trying to use Linqpad so as to use LINQ instead of TSQL when trying to remove some records from a table that is part of a "dependency tree" that spans probably 10-12 tables.  So I created some tables in a test db and im experimenting with the DeleteAllOnSubmit and SubmitChanges methods.
I get an FK error.  Yet, Im deleting the child objects first.  How do I delete when there is FK relations (without using cascading on the FK's)?

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_OrderItem_Order". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table
>   "dbo.OrderItem", c...

Tables:

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Order]    Script Date: 6/9/2016 2:50:18 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderNum] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OrderItem]    Script Date: 6/9/2016 2:50:18 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderItem](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderItemName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderItem_Order] FOREIGN KEY([OrderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Order] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderItem_Order]
GO
```

Here is my LINQ statement

```
List<Order> olist  = (from a in Orders where a.Id == 2 select a).ToList();
List<int> olistidlist = olist.Select (o => o.Id).ToList();

List<OrderItem> oilist = (from a in OrderItems where olistidlist.Contains(a.Id) select a).ToList();

//see results before
olist.Dump();

OrderItems.DeleteAllOnSubmit(oilist);
Orders.DeleteAllOnSubmit(olist);


//save changes
SubmitChanges();

//see results after
olist.Dump();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting `OrderItem`s of which the `OrderItem.Id` is equal to values in `olistidlist` (only 2, presently). Of course, this must be `OrderItem.OrderId`.

By the way, an easier way to delete parent and child items generally is:

```cs
foreach (var order in Orders.Where(...))
{
    OrderItems.DeleteAllOnSubmit(order.OrderItems);
    Orders.DeleteOnSubmit(order);
}
```

So you don't have to move around with Id values.